# Drupal commerce taxonomy

Tags: nodes, commerce, taxonomy-terms

I have made taxonomy categories for products, and block where is category link list, but how I can make target url for these categories and when user go to category link there is page and all products in that category is listed?

Answer (score 0):

You create a link to the taxonomy display page. This page will show all the nodes (product display types) that are tagged with the taxonomy term (category). How you display the taxonomy page is up to you. There are many modules which can give you more flexibility to the taxonomy display pages.